# Sitecore 9.0.2 Installation certificate issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

There is error about certificates when I ran the installation scripts.

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : No registration found for extension 'NewRootCertificate' of type 'Task'.
At C:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:17 char:1

- Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you have tried the installation script more than once, you can have some undesired behavior. You are possibly trying to go forward with the wrong certificates. Also, some of these services were actually created on previous installation attempts.

Here is what I think should help you get through.

**Clean your workspace**

- Remove your databases that are related to the installation if exists.
- Remove your certificates (using certlm -> you can type in your windows search bar "cert" and then you should be able to pick "Manage computer Certificate".

  - On the left sidebar, Click on Personal > Certificates.

    - Remove your installation-related certificates

      - nameOfYourInstallation.identityserver
      - nameOfYourInstallation.sc
      - nameOfYourInstallation.xconnect
- Open your Windows Services Manager (you can type in your windows search bar "services" and select the services app)

  - You should be able to see those services :

    - Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - nameOfYourInstallation(might be one of your previous install)
    - Sitecore Processing Engine - nameOfYourInstallation
    - Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - nameOfYourInstallation.

      - Write those down. Keep your service app open.
  - Using NSSM (probably installed already from some of your previous installed, if not, can use chocolatey ( https://chocolatey.org/packages/NSSM ) remove those services.
  - in a cmd : nssm remove serviceName

    - Note that you can remove them by right clicking etc. I just prefer the nssm way.
- When its done, restart your computer (some services and in a state of removal, that needs a restart to be completely removed)
- Try to install with SIA again.